# Por que me imprime por pasos?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, lista

Tengo este código en c# el problema es cuando Presionó el boton imprir no me imprime el resultado completo si no que tengo que apretar el botón dos veces o mas para que me imprima toda el texto

Estos datos se imprimen en un texbox cada uno

```
List<string> letra = new List<string>();
List<string> numeros = new List<string>();
List<string> operador = new List<string>();
private string texto;        


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AgrgarDato(txtExpresion.Text);
    this.Operador1();
    this.imprimir();
}


public void AgrgarDato(string num)
{
    texto = num;
}

public List<string> Operador1()
{
    string n = "";
    string l = "";
    string p = "";
    char[] dat = texto.ToArray();
    Array.Reverse(dat);
    for (int i = 0; i < dat.Length; i++)
    {
        if (dat[i] == ')' || dat[i] == '+' || dat[i] == '-' || dat[i] == '*' || dat[i] == '/' || dat[i] == '(')
        {
            l += dat[i].ToString();
            operador.Add(l);
        }
        else if(dat[i] == 'a' || dat[i] == 'b' || dat[i] == 'c' || dat[i] == 'd' || dat[i] == 'e' || dat[i] == 'f')
        {
            p += dat[i].ToString();
            letra.Add(p);
        }
        else
        {
            n += dat[i].ToString();
            numeros.Add(n);
        }   
    }
    return operador;
}

public void imprimir()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < texto.Length; i++)
    {
        textBox1.Text = letra[i];
        textBox2.Text = operador[i];
        textBox3.Text = numeros[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde y cómo mandas a llamar a imprimir()? No lo muestras en tu código... Cabe hacer notar que el MessageBox hará que se detenga el ciclo for en cada iteración.

Comment: Ok, viendo tu código, lo único que se me ocurre es que el ciclo for es detenido por el MessageBox en cada iteración. No veo en qué momento agregas los datos en los textbox que mencionas.

Comment: Me refiero al ciclo for que tienes en el método imprimir()

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras ya esta editado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los Arrays que estas creando **numeros**, **operador**, y **letra** tendrán una longitud inferior al número de caracteres del texto, ya que por ejemplo para el texto *(abc5)* el array numeros tendrá una longitud de 1, el array letra de 3, y el array operador de 2. Si recorres el bucle 4 veces (tanto como número de caracteres) accederas a elementos que no existen como **numeros[3]** y se producira un error. En caso de que llames a **Operador1()** varias veces, los arrays se rellenan con los mismos caracteres hasta que tengan un tamaño mayor o igual a 4, y entonces se imprimen repetiendose.

Comment: y  hay alguna manera de arreglarlo?

Comment: Deberías recorrer en tres bucles distintos, las distintas Listas numeros, operador, y letra. Cada una de ellas teniendo en cuenta su tamaño.

Comment: Gracias por la idea ya esta lo hice con tres bucles y funciona

Comment: @HadesGonzález ¿si no funciono lo que comenta en esta publicación porque la señalas como la respuesta correcta?